# How to override existing Backbone Model method keeping other methods same

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, backbone.js

I have a backbone model which I don't have access to edit.So i want to modify the method of it, so that other methods functionality wont affect.

```
ShoppingDetail = Backbone.Model.extend({
   className: 'CartID',
   fetch: function() {},
   checkForChanges: function() {},
   newCoupon: function() {},
   saveAndallow: function() {}
 });

 shoppingDetailModel = new ShoppingDetail();
 shoppingCartView = new ShoppingCartView({
   model: shoppingDetailModel
 });
```

So i want to override saveAndallow method of the model.How could i do that without affecting other methods of that model

Comment: Did the below answer work for you ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you create a new Model which will extend your ShoppingDetail Model ?

```
ShoppingDetail = Backbone.Model.extend({ 
    className: 'CartID', 
    fetch: function() {},
    checkForChanges : function() {},
    newCoupon: function(){},
    saveAndallow: function(){}
});

NewShoppingDetail = ShoppingDetail.extend({
    saveAndallow: function(){};
});

shoppingDetailModel = new NewShoppingDetail();
shoppingCartView =  new ShoppingCartView({
        model : shoppingDetailModel
});
```

So now, when you call any method, it will first check if it is available in NewShoppingDetail, if not available, then it will check ShoppingDetail.